# how to edit view of layout in parent when use RecyclerView?

Tags: android-recyclerview

i use one adapter and one layout for 2 recyclerView. I want to edit view of layout in specific recyclerView, how can it do that?

this is my adapter

```
class PictureAdapter(private val onclickToRemove: ((Int) -> Unit?)?,
                     private val onclickToZoom: ((String) -> Unit?)?
                     , private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PictureAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val picture = itemView.findViewById<RoundedImageView>(R.id.itemPicture)
        private val btnRemove = itemView.findViewById<RoundedImageView>(R.id.btnRemovePicture)
        private val pictureName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.itemPictureName)

        fun onBind(item: PictureModel) {
            Glide.with(context).load(item.urlPicture).into(picture)
            pictureName.text = item.pictureName
            btnRemove.setOnClickListener {
                onclickToRemove?.invoke(adapterPosition)
            }
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onclickToZoom?.invoke(item.urlPicture)
            }
        }
    }
    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PictureModel>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: PictureModel, newItem: PictureModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem.urlPicture == newItem.urlPicture
        }
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: PictureModel, newItem: PictureModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_picture,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val picture = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.onBind(picture)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }
}
```

**my english not well so i hope you sympathize for me ,i wish you have a nice day!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide or show your view by conditional rendering.
Example:

```
val tvName = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_item_user);
tvName.Visibility = View.VISIBLE; // View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE are available too.
```

Suppose you are calling your adapter from ActivityA, then you pass a flag like
`flag: 1` and when you are calling your adapter from ActivityB then pass `flag: 2`. You receive the flag value from adapter and rendering your view based on flag 1 or 2.

For a example, Your layout_item.xml file has 2 TextView.
One is for nameTextView and another is schoolTextView. When you get flag value 1 then you just show nameTextView and hide schoolTextView. When you get flag value 2 then you show schoolTextView and hide nameTextView.

In your case, you add a flag parameter with adapter class. Pass flag no when you call/initialisation your adapter. Inside `onBind()` function of `MyViewHolder` class you can hide and show your view with your own requirements.